# Can't hide popup on IOS and OSX

Tags: javascript, ios

I have popup with cookies info and code in js to hide it after click button and then create a cookie to not show popup in the future.
It's working on on the android, chrom, firefox etc. but not working on the Iphone and OSX.

Why?

```
var box = document.getElementById('gdpr-info');
var button = document.getElementById('close');

function getCookie(name) {
var dc = document.cookie;
var prefix = name + "=";
var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
if (begin == -1) {
    begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
    if (begin != 0) return null;
}
else
{
    begin += 2;
    var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
    if (end == -1) {
    end = dc.length;
    }
}

return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    } 

var myCookie = getCookie("readed");

if (myCookie == "yes") {
    box.style.display = 'none';
}

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.cookie = "readed=yes;";
    box.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific about "it's not working". What's not working exactly? Does it throw an error in your console?

Comment: Popup won't hide after clicking the button

Comment: ok, strange, your code looks ok. However, one thing might cause an issue, depending on when your javascript is loaded: is `var box = document.getElementById('gdpr-info');` already part of the DOM when this javascript runs? If you're not using jQuery, it's a bit difficult if you need 100% browser compatibility to wrap everything in a check that the DOM tree is ready (`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { //do work });` works almost everywhere not IE8 and below). But make sure your javascript is placed after `<body>`.

Comment: btw do you see any errors in your javascript console in Safari? You would see an error if my above assumption is correct.

Comment: Script is loaded before </body> tag, i have no errors in console.

Comment: have you tried wrapping your script in a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener?

Comment: I finally fixed it. I just set display: none; in style.css sheet and replaced if (myCookie != "yes") {
    box.style.display = 'block';
} with if (myCookie == "yes") {
    box.style.display = 'none';
}

Comment: I have no idea why it is working just now... But now popup will hide on IOS when button is clicked.